# How to set permission for IIS AppPool identity when creating website in Wix Toolset?

Tags: iis, wix, wix3

I'm writing a Wix Toolset installer to install an Angular + asp.net core application in IIS on Windows Server 2016. I create a new Website and a new Application Pool. I want to grant full permission to the Application Pool identity on the newly created website folder path. 
I followed the step given here : https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/115036/Creating-WIX-Installer-for-ASP-NET-Web-Application? so I have 3 files :

- Setup.wxs
- IISConfiguration.wxs
- WebSiteContent.wxs

I set up the website and permissions in IISConfiguration.wxs.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="WEBSITE">    
        <Component Id="WebSiteSiteNameCmp" Guid="{ED376FD7-D4DB-4675-8BF4-1DCC1AF1C66B}" KeyPath="yes" >
            <iis:WebSite Id="WebSiteName"
                  Description='WebSiteName'
                  Directory="WEBSITE"
                  AutoStart="no"
                  ConfigureIfExists="yes"
                  StartOnInstall="no" >
              <iis:WebAddress Id="WebSiteAdressHttps" Port="443" IP="*" Secure="yes"/>
              <iis:WebAddress Id="WebSiteAdressHttp" Port="80" IP="*" Secure="no"/>
              <iis:WebDirProperties Id="WebSiteProperties" AnonymousAccess="yes"
                BasicAuthentication="no" WindowsAuthentication="no" />
              <iis:WebApplication Id="WebSiteNameSite" Name="WebSite" WebAppPool="WebSiteAppPool" />
            </iis:WebSite>
        </Component>

        <!-- Configuring app pool -->
        <Component Id="WebSiteAppPoolCmp" Guid="{009052A8-19AE-452e-AE34-6DC8E929DA08}"
        KeyPath="yes" Permanent="yes"  Win64="yes">
        <iis:WebAppPool Id="WebSiteAppPool" Name="WebSiteAppPoolName" ManagedPipelineMode="integrated" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="WebSitePermissionCmp" Guid="{4425EFB0-A580-44B7-9C04-54EBD2E4ECB1}">
             <CreateFolder> 
               <util:PermissionEx User="IIS AppPool\WebSiteAppPoolName" GenericAll="yes"/> 
             </CreateFolder> 
         </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

But then the installer rollsback because the AppPool isn't created yet when trying to set permissions on the folder. I have the following error in my logs :

```
 ExecSecureObjects: Error 0x80070534: failed to get sid for account: IIS AppPool\WebSiteAppPoolName.
```

What should I do to set the permissions at the "good" time ?

Comment: it sounds like the application pool haven't been created when premisseionex trying to grant permission. Have you checked whether your script are able to create a new application pool?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13668777/creating-application-pool-in-wix-installer

Comment: If I remove the component "WebSitePermissionCmp". The installation finishes without problem, the app pool is created.

I try to set the app pool component inside the "WebSiteSiteNameCmp" but I still have the same rollback with the same error :

ExecSecureObjects:  Error 0x80070534: failed to get sid for account: IIS AppPool\WebSiteAppPoolName.

Comment: I did a lot of research but I haven't find a workaround so far. Have you tried to use a specific user instead of application pool identity?

Comment: I wish I could do that, however the installer is intended for multiple clients with the same amount of different server. I don't know any credentials that will be use to install.

Comment: Is it possible to create a user to manage application pool instead in wix toolset? https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/util/user.html

Comment: I'm not very good with Wix toolset, I only followed some tutorials specifically made for installing web site under IIS. I do not really get the pure API of the WIX toolset. May be one day, with practice ^^
I finally manage to do what I wanted with a custom action. I will post the answer if anyone need to to this with a custom action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally used the custom action solution with icalcs to manage the permissions on the newly created application pool. This is what I add in my Setup.wxs :

```
<CustomAction Id='AppPoolPermission' Directory='WEBSITE' 
ExeCommand='"[SystemFolder]icacls.exe" "[INSTALLDIR]." /grant "IIS AppPool\WebSiteAppPoolName:(OI)(CI)F" /T' Return='check'/>   

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='AppPoolPermission' After='InstallFinalize' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

I also removed the WebSitePermissionCmp from IISConfiguration.wxs.
It's not the ideal solution but for me it works. I don't know if this can be achieved only with WIX without custom action.

Another post concerning this issue : [How to specify the AppPool Identity in a WiX Permission Element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241272/how-to-specify-the-apppool-identity-in-a-wix-permission-element)
I don't fully understand the answer but it also seem to be using custom actions.